# Unknow Host proble on Google Compute Engine

Tags: google-compute-engine

I have my application hosted on Google Compute Engine.
Since 13 Apr I am facing Unknown Host error while issuing ping command to any domain. 
The issue is intermittent. Most of the time the ping command is working but intermittently it will return unknown host error. 
Is there anyone else facing the same issue on Compute Engine?
On the same day an incident was reported to google with network issue
https://status.cloud.google.com/incident/compute/16007

As per them the issue is resolved now but I am still getting the error.
Please help.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be asked of Google Support.